# Listen to events from node.js server (Android)

Tags: android, node.js, listener

I am making an android chat app, I made a Node.js server file which emits events but I want to know how I can listen to the events in the client-side (Android). Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you expect that to work? Your web server would have to always be tracking your Android device to know how/where to send a message. (Note: I'm not saying impossible, just I want you to think about it)

Comment: I heard there's a way to do it by using Emitter.Listener. But not sure how to implement it

Comment: like this? https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat/blob/master/README.md

Comment: yes, similar to that

Comment: And what is stopping you from implementing that?

Comment: I was not able to find the link before. Thanks